How I can find the nearest value of a row of the entire values in other column if there not exist an equal value
I want to map the age_in_monts to the same age in months but if the age does not exist in the other column then map the age with the nearest age.
For example, I can use the if statement to check if the age_in_months is equal to the age of the other column but if not then I want to map the age_in_monts to the nearest age.
This is the data frame
I used a for loop
for i in df3['AGE_IN_MONTHS']:
    if i == df3['Age']:

I also used this method but I got different results
closest = df3.iloc[(df3['AGE_IN_MONTHS']-df3['Age']).abs()[:1]]


What do you mean by map? Are you trying to find the value or the index that closer matches each value in age_in_months? i == df3['Age'] doesn't make sense because one single age value can not be equal to a column of values, so it would help to know the real goal, i.e. what do you want to do with that value.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors. Use df.to_dict to create a dictionary with a few rows that we can copy. See How to make good reproducible pandas examples.

Ignatius Reilly. First, I'm sorry for not being clear about the question.  I'm inserting new age_in_months into the data frame using the input function in Python.  I want to check if the age_in_monts exists in the age then align in the same row with the age that already exists but If that age does not exist then align with the nearest age that is in the age column. thank you

Does this answer your question? How do I find the closest values in a Pandas series to an input number?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

not exactly, I think I'm not being clear about my question. l update the question to make it more clear. thank you -Ignatius Reilly
